# Wordpress, how to do third party authentication?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

How to do authentication from a third-party resource, similar to Google, Facebook.

I have a service to which I send my login and password, in response i get some data (unique id, role, etc.). Next, on the WP side, I need to save and work with additional user data (name, email, address, ...).

How connect ID(third party service) to a user on the WP side?

Comment: [This link here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-apps-login/) is a plugin specifically for logging in through Google.

Comment: [And this link here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-login-openid/) is plugin that will integrate Facebook, Google, Twitter and lots of other social auth. solutions.

If none of them are the one you need to use, then I'm afraid that you will have to either search custom solution or make it yourself. WordPress has some great documentation how to user REST API authentication [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/)